# Haskell recursion in lists

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I have code like this:

```hs
appd (a:e) ((c,b):bs) | a == c && bs /= [] = b:appd(a:e) bs
                      | a /= c && bs /= [] = appd (a:e) bs
                      | a /= c && bs == [] = appd e ((c,b):bs)
                      | otherwise          = b:appd e ((c,b):bs)
```

It loops throught two lists like `[1,2,3]` and `[(1,2),(6,5),(3,5)]` and takes first element of first list and compares it to first element of each tuple in other list, if they are equal then save second element of this tuple. It works fine, but comparison does not work if I take second element of first list, in this case `2`.

For example if I have lists like `[1,2,3]` and `[(1,2),(6,5),(3,5)]`, then function takes `1` from first list and compares to `1`, then to `6`, then to `3`, that works but it does not take second element of first list - `2` and does not do the comparison again. Whats wrong?

Comment: Could not reproduce: in my tests, it is indeed returning results paired up with `1`, `2`, and `3`; for example, `appd [1,2,3] [(1,2),(6,5),(3,5)]` appears to correctly return both the `2` from `(1,2)` and the `5` from `(3,5)` before crashing. If I add a `(2,4)` at the end, it does return the `4` before crashing. However, this function is badly partial -- it eventually crashes on almost every input. Perhaps if you fix that (try inspecting the output of GHC with `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` on), it will behave more like you want it to.

Comment: The way to answer your question is to take the test case which you've isolated (`appd [1,2,3] [(1,2),(6,5),(3,5)]`) and follow it's execution carefully in your head, on paper, or with a debugger, and to think hard.

Comment: I tried, but I can't see mistake

Comment: What do you mean by _"save second element of this tuple"_? what does "saving" mean here? by saving do you mean that the output lists will contain that item? with `[1,2,3]` and `[(1,2),(6,5),(3,5)]`, should `appd` return `[1,3]`? do the input lists have to have equal lengths? is the 2nd element of the tuples ever used at all?

Comment: It takes number 1 from first list and compares to second lists each tuple first element, it compares 1 to 1, 1 to 6, 1 to 3 if comparison is true then it adds to result tuples second element, in this case it would be 1. Then it takes next element from firt list and does the copmarison again - 2 to 1, 2 to 6, 2 to 3.....

Answer (score 1):

*First of all, let me note that you should have included the error message you were getting. You should also have shown us some sample output and sample input.*

---

Anyway: your current `appd` doesn't handle empty lists, so you need to start by adding cases for that:

```hs
appd _     []          = []
appd []    bs          = snd <$> bs  -- you can decide to use [] instead
appd (a:e) ((c,b):bs)
  | a == c && bs /= [] = b:appd(a:e) bs
  | a /= c && bs /= [] = appd (a:e) bs
  | a /= c && bs == [] = appd e ((c,b):bs)
  | otherwise          = b:appd e ((c,b):bs)
```

now your function works on the input you've provided, but I'm not sure it returns the results you desire:

```hs
*Main> appd [1,2,3] [(1,2),(6,5),(3,5)]
[2,5,5]
```

---

**Furthermore**, I've cleaned up your code a little bit and annotated your function with an explicit type signature:

```hs
appd :: (Eq a, Eq b) => [a] -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
appd []         bs      = snd <$> bs
appd _          []      = []
appd as@(a:ass) bs@((c,b):bss)
  | a == c && bss /= [] = b : appd as  bss
  | a /= c && bss /= [] =     appd as  bss
  | a /= c && bss == [] =     appd ass bs
  | otherwise           = b : appd ass bs
```

---

**Also**, you can use a much simpler, non-recursive implementation to get the same results as above:

```hs
appd :: (Eq a, Eq b) => [a] -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
appd as bs = snd <$> filter (\(a,_) -> a `elem` as) bs
```

or if you like [point free](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) (a.k.a. [tacit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming)):

```hs
appd :: (Eq a, Eq b) => [a] -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
appd as = (snd <$>) . filter ((`elem` as) . fst)
```

---

**Note:**  `<$>` is an alias for `fmap`, which in turn behaves exactly like `map` when used on lists.

Comment: ah, yes, I forgot to mention what `<$>` does.

Comment: Thank you a lot!! Unfortunately my function still does not work even with imrovements, but your suggested simplier implementation works fine. Here is sample input:[1,2,3,4][(1,5),(3,8),(5,5),(4,3),(2,9)] output: [5,9,8,3]

Comment: O, sorry, checked again - also simplier version gives incorrect output

Comment: It takes elements from first list one by one, than compares it  with tuples from other list. It compares element from first list with each tuples first element and if they are equal then second element from tuple is added to result. In this case it takes 1 from first list and compare it to 1, 3, 5, 4 and 2 => 1=1 so add 5 to result. Then it takes 2 and repeats the same action